# devise custom flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to access current_user.username in my flash message after registering.  How do I go about doing this?  Can this be done in the devise.en.yml file?

Answer (score 20):

I think you have to overwrite registration controller in order to customize your flash message.

If you take a look at devise.en.yml file, you can see that some variables like `%{resource}` or `%{count}` are used. By taking a look at original registration controller, you can see this code ( [check here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) )

```
# POST /resource
def create
build_resource(sign_up_params)

if resource.save
  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  respond_with resource
end
```

end

I would rewrite this controller and add this line

```
set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up, :username => resource.username if is_flashing_format?
```

Then in your `devise.en.yml` file, you should be able to use something like that

```
devise:
  registrations:
    signed_up: 'oh hello %{username}'
```

Tell me if that worked.

If you need hint on how to rewrite Devise controller, take a look at [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)

Hope it helped.

===== UPDATE =====

I tested it and it worked.

Okay so if we want to go deeper, we can check `lib/devise/controllers/internal_helpers.rb` :

```
# Sets the flash message with :key, using I18n. By default you are able
# to setup your messages using specific resource scope, and if no one is
# found we look to default scope.
# Example (i18n locale file):
#
# en:
# devise:
# passwords:
# #default_scope_messages - only if resource_scope is not found
# user:
# #resource_scope_messages
#
# Please refer to README or en.yml locale file to check what messages are
# available.
def set_flash_message(key, kind, options={}) #:nodoc:
  options[:scope] = "devise.#{controller_name}"
  options[:default] = Array(options[:default]).unshift(kind.to_sym)
  options[:resource_name] = resource_name
  message = I18n.t("#{resource_name}.#{kind}", options)
  flash[key] = message if message.present?
end
```

But please update your code so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: I ran rails g controller Registrations and copied and pasted in the original devise code.  I then modified the appropriate line as you suggested and the devise.en.yml file as well.  I get this error:          missing interpolation argument in "Sign up Complete, %{username}" ({:resource_name=>:user} given)

Comment: Mmm re-reading your comment, i have the feeling that you forgot to tell Rails to use your new controller for registrations. Please follow that: In config/routes.rb add :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" } to your devise_for root. (see again that [tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) )

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you're finished with that. Thanks

Comment: It's a joke that edit just got approved.  If people want to post an updated answer because an underlying lib has changed then they should post an updated answer - not alter an answer that is perfectly valid for an older version of a library!